# Mark packets across computers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables, qos

I use Transmission on Ubuntu and I'm having this [issue](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/776), which basically says that QoS is broken because there is no way to limit which outgoing ports uses.

I was thinking of doing a dirty and ugly hack and create an interface alias and define QoS based on source address, but was wondering if is there another way. Is it possible to mark the packets on the original machine in some way, using the `owner` and `mark` modules of `iptables` and sending this to the router who does the QoS?

From what I understand, `mark` on `iptables` only applies to the local machine, so this will not work, but is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iptables with `-j DSCP` to modify the [DSCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DiffServ) field in IP header (both v4 and v6).